# How to get JSON file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

In my app I have directory `server` and sub-directory `x` and within this directory there is a file called `x.js` (written using node.js).

In another sub-directory of `server` there is a `y.json` file; I want to use its content in `x.js`.

It must be very easy, but nothing yet has helped me,

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just include it in your js file

```
var myJson = require('path_to_your_json');
// json file contains {"myValue": "resolved"}

console.log(myJson.myValue); // Prints "resolved";
```